# XSLT 2.0 - iterate over a list of Java objects

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XSL that is meant to create a copy of an XML but with a few attributes added to certain elements in the XML. The XSL calls a Java function that returns a list (java.util.List) of objects of type CInfo which is *currently* a very simple class defined as follows:

```
public class CInfo {
    public int getNewVal() {
        return 12345;
    }
}
```

I am now facing a problem with the following snippet in the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:list="java.util.List"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    ...
    ...>

...
<xsl:variable name="infoList"
    select="up:computeUpdates($updator)"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$infoList">
    <xsl:variable name="cinfo" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="newVal" select="ci:getNewVal($cinfo)"/>
...
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

*computeUpdates()*, which I verified is indeed being called by XSL, returns a list containing just one instance of type CInfo. The problem occurs at *xsl:for-each* which gives the following error:

```
Error on line 89
  XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item
  type java:com.mproj.mpkg.CInfo
  at xsl:for-each (#76)
     processing "com.mproj.mpkg.."
  at xsl:apply-templates (#48)
```

Somehow the XSL doesn't seem to be able to iterate over *infoList*. Strangely, an existing XSL in the codebase that I am working on has a very similar *for-each* and is able to iterate over a list of Java objects of another class (similar to CInfo though) and doesn't seem to give any problem. Am I missing something? What is the standard procedure to make an XSLT iterate over a list of Java objects? Any examples that can help me here? I tried searching the web for examples of such looping and possible solutions to the mentioned problem but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us line 89, where the error arises. My guess is that it probably contains an expression of the form

$infoList/XXXXX

which is failing because (as the error message explains) the lh operand of "/" must be a sequence of nodes.

Comment: or indeed any relative XPath expression inside the `for-each` (whose context "node" is a `CInfo` object, not a node).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I had completely missed the fact that the error was being by a line (#89) within _for-each_ block and not by _for-each_ itself. That line had the following:

 `<xsl:apply-templates select="./Elem1/Elem2[@low = $a]/..">`

and as rightly pointed out by Michael and Ian, that expression was incorrect. After modifying the _select_ expression to `"$topNode/Elem1/Elem2[@low = $a]/.."`, the XSL seems to be working. Thanks for the help!